# SubView hierarchies not working (SubView hidden below another)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, xcode5

I'm having a problem here with designing my UI in Xcode.

I've programmatically created(when a button is pressed) a UIImageView(black, transparent overlay), UITextView(editable), and a UIButton to clear these former two UISubviews.

This problem is all appearing both on the Simulator, and my iPhone.

This is my code

```
- (IBAction)openCommentTextView:(id)sender {
    doneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 60, 35)];
    doneButton.alpha = 0.0;
    doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
    doneButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    doneButton.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    doneButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:15];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(finishEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    commentTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 280, 230)];
    [commentTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    commentTextView.alpha = 0.0;
    if ([commentsTextViewViewer.text  isEqual: @"Comment..."]) {
        commentsTextViewViewer.text = @"";
    } else {
        commentTextView.text = commentsTextViewViewer.text;
    }
    commentTextView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
    commentTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
    commentTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:20];
    commentTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.4];

    backgroundOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 330, 568)];
    backgroundOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    backgroundOverlay.alpha = 0.0;


    [self.view insertSubview:doneButton atIndex:11];
    [self.view insertSubview:commentTextView atIndex:10];
    [self.view insertSubview:backgroundOverlay atIndex:9];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    commentTextView.alpha = 1.0;
    doneButton.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    backgroundOverlay.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

However, somehow the UIButton(doneButton) and the UITextView(commentTextView) is under the UIImageView(black overlay). Both the UIButton and the UITextView responds. (I set the UIImageView(black overlay) alpha to `1.0`, and the UIButton and UITextView didn't appear, although both responded)

It turned out like [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwC8PzenJAl3b1RmWFdSQzVNQnc/edit) (sorry I couldn't include the image directly into here... I didn't have enough reputation)

But when I copied this code and pasted into a new single-view application, it worked perfectly as I wished it to. [(like this)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwC8PzenJAl3bmYxZTVzMEJObE0/edit)

I really have no idea why this is happening... I've searched all over the web but with no success.

Is this something to do with XCode, or my iPhone itself?

I'd be very happy if someone can help me work this out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that might help.  I've never had much luck in terms of the `atIndex:` method of view insertion except index `0`.  Try using relative position, since you know the button and textview NEED to be above the background overlay.

```
[self.view addSubview:backgroundOverlay];
[self.view insertSubview:doneButton aboveSubview:backgroundOverlay];
[self.view insertSubview:commentTextView aboveSubview:backgroundOverlay];
```

Also, you'll need a second call to `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` before animating the second bit of code.  Or, alternatively, use the [UIView animation blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) which is recommended if you're targeting iOS 4 or higher.

Comment: Yesss I've finally fixed it. I wonder why the `atIndex:` doesn't work.

Comment: Also, yes I have to fix the animation as well, I simply forgot it. And I also used to use blocks for UIView Animaitions, but somehow the animation got stuck and didn't go smoothly so I had to write like this. But thank you for all the advice!

Comment: @CloudyLily0009 it's probably because indexes 9, 10, & 11 are beyond the bounds of the subview array.  In which case, it behaves like `addSubview` and just appends them to the end.